# moment.js displays wrong time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm using jQuery.countdown and moment.js to create a multiple instance/time zone aware countdown timer. Everything works except the time zone. Throwing in the time zone changes the countdown to GMT, not the zone that I specify. No matter what time zone I choose, the timer stays at GMT.

```js
        $(function(){
            $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
           var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
     var finalDate = moment.tz(finalDate, 'America/Los_Angeles');
           $this.countdown(finalDate.toDate(), function(event) {
   var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;
    $(this).html(event.strftime('Expires in ' + totalHours + ' hr %-M min'));
           });
         });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine?

[Here is a fiddle logging out both Los Angeles time then New York time for same Moment object](https://jsbin.com/biluhiyoye/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

with the code being simply:

```
$(function(){
  var finalDate = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", 'America/Los_Angeles');
  console.log(
    finalDate.format("ha z"),
    finalDate.tz('America/New_York').format("ha z"))

  var nextYear = moment.tz("2018-04-21 00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo");
  $('#clock').countdown(nextYear.toDate(), function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
  });
})
```

Did you check console for any error messages?

Because I saw this at first:

> "Moment Timezone has no data for America/Los_Angeles. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/."

before realizing I had to include the moment-timezone-with-data package instead of the vanilla moment-timezone to get it to work.

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.

(edited code bin to include a Jquery countdown working example)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm including moment.js and moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js. No errors.

Comment: Hmm. What version of Moment, just in case its an early/unsupported version? BTW, edited the linked fiddle, I had used an old link previously

Comment: Version 0.5.14. Tried re-downloading just in case, still the same.

Comment: Wait, version 0.5.14?? Because the plugin doc states *"To use moment-timezone, you will need moment@2.9.0+, moment-timezone.js, and the moment-timezone data."*

Comment: Sorry, was looking at moment timezone. Its version 2.22.1, latest version from the site.

Comment: The fiddle example works for me, I assume it works for you too. We can be reasonably confident Jquery is fine. Leads me to think that issue is with countdown plugin. [Is this the plugin?](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#events). Note that lists support up to Jquery v2.1. Might need to see more sample code

Comment: OK updated the above post with [another jsbin link that has countdown working](https://jsbin.com/biluhiyoye/1/edit?html,js,console,output). Note that I tested with both Jquery 2.1 and 3.1 and it seems to work.

Comment: Yours works, but I need the functionality of multiple countdown timers.