# Message time mess up

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, message

so when I chat on my chat room the message time shows a different time than what my real time is. For example, the message might say 7:30pm when it's 12:30pm right now. The code for the messages is:

```
const moment = require('moment');

function formatMessage(username, text) {
  return {
    username,
    text, 
    time: moment().format('dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss a')
  };
}

module.exports = formatMessage;
```

I don't know if anything is wrong or if the server is just messing up.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your browser console? Have you included the `moment-timezone-with-data` package? See [moment.js displays wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868216/moment-js-displays-wrong-time).

Comment: @showdev—the OP makes no use of moment.tz so there is no need to include it.

Comment: I don't see any errors and what is wrong with line 1?

Comment: @showdev—the OP has included [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) for the `moment().format(…)` call, there is no need to load [moment.tz](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) unless timezone functions are required. There is nothing in the OP to indicate they are.

Comment: @RobG Sorry, I overlooked "tz" part of your comment. I was speculating that the wrong time might indicate a timezone issue. But maybe not.

Comment: That is true. I will look more into it.